# I created ads with AdMob. Ad appears while using test ID. I do not see any ads when I use my ID. why?

Tags: admob

I created ads with AdMob. Ad appears while using test ID. I do not see any ads when I use my ID. why ? Could it be after the game has been released? can google adsmobs not allowing this? thanks..

Comment: Did you try it on a real device?
Make sure you changed the id everywhere you use it

Comment: yes I tried it on the phone. I can not see an ad when I enter my ID.

Comment: There are two forms of IDs, `ca-app-pub-xx/xx` and `ca-app-pub-yy~yy` one with `/` and one with a `~`. Make sure you use the correct ID. Tell me if that's not the issue